# Region error when launching EMR cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, elastic-map-reduce, emr

I'm following this tutorial https://aws.amazon.com/articles/4926593393724923

to create and launch a simple spark cluster, Im interested in using spark streaming and kinesis so i created a role with the following policy

{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "cloudwatch:*",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "kinesis:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "sns:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}

And i get this error when running the --create command from the cli

ruby elastic-mapreduce --create --alive --name "Spark-
Kinesis"  --bootstrap-action s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/spark/0.8.1/install-s
park-shark.sh --bootstrap-name "Spark/Shark"  --instance-type m1.xlarge --instan
ce-count 3 --jobflow-role spark
Error: Credential should be scoped to a valid region, not 'us-west-2'.
emr-cli/aws/core/client.rb:368:in `return_or_raise'
emr-cli/aws/core/client.rb:469:in`client_request'
(eval):3:in `get_instance_profile'
emr-cli/iam_client_wrapper.rb:69:in`instance_profile_exists?'

emr-cli/commands.rb:1190:in `validate'
emr-cli/commands.rb:45:in`block in validate'
emr-cli/commands.rb:45:in `each'
emr-cli/commands.rb:45:in`validate'
emr-cli/commands.rb:2420:in `create_and_execute_commands'
emr-cli/elastic-mapreduce-cli.rb:13:in`'
Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in`require'
elastic-mapreduce:6:in `'

The region for my key-pair is us-west-2, so im not sure whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `us-east-1`. If it works, it means you are using the AWS client which still has the problem where they used the target region for IAM as well. IAM only supports requests scoped to `us-east-1`.

I believe there was a fix to this problem:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/issues/508